# file input validate size client side on older version of internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, validation, internet-explorer, filesize

(sorry for my english)

I need to validate size of some html file input's on the client side before submitting my form, because i am the attaching the files uploads to a mail sent in php to gmail and gmail limits the email size up to 25MB.

Now im testing it in IE8 and it dosent have files API (i'm not an expert) due to security reasons, so my current javascript code dosent "support" it..

I found some Activex mathods but they dosent seem to be very promising because it needs to be activated on IE browser and i cant control the user.

any ideas?

Jvascript code i use to validate on other browser's (except IE):

```
else if(file_check.files[0].size >  2560000){
    file_check.style.borderColor = "red";
    validFlag = false;
    msg += " -Max file size is 2.5MB" + "\n";
}
```

HTML:

```
<input style="width:220px" required name="files[]" type="file" id="show_image_height">
```

Answer (score 0):

Question already answered if you have done some searching .

> No, there is no JavaScript-only polyfill/shim/etc. for this feature on
>   browsers like IE8 and IE9 that don't support the File API. Nor can
>   there be. That's why we have the File API in modern browsers.
>
> If you feel strongly about offering client-side validation to
>   supplement your server-side validation, you'll have to go with
>   ActiveX, Flash, or Java applet solutions.

Comment: thnx for your answer